# How does the Contract Law definition of 'consumer surplus' relate to the Microeconomics definition?

Tags: law

[*O'Sullivan & Hilliard's The Law of Contract*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/OSullivan-Hilliards-Law-Contract-Janet/dp/0198807821/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) (2018 8 ed). 16.23 starts on p. 387, 16.35 on p. 391.

Right: Pindyck, Rubinfeld. [*Microeconomics, Global Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1292213310) (2017 9 ed). p. 152.

> [image]

[Richard](https://www.uclan.ac.uk/staff_profiles/richard-taylor.php) and [Damian](https://www.slaughterandmay.com/who-we-are/partners/damian-taylor/) Taylor. [*Contract Law Directions* (2019 7 ed)](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/contract-law-directions-9780198836599?&lang=en&).

> **Difference in value or cost of cure? (Section 11.3.1)**
>   The £2,500 award made in *Ruxley* for Mr Forsyth’s ‘loss of amenity’ can be interpreted as
>   damages for non-pecuniary loss, based on the fact that the contract was a consumer
>   contract for enjoyment (see the opinions of Lords Clyde and Hutton in *Farley v Skinner*
>   (2001)). However, the award may also be interpreted as a response to the need for a
>   wider principle of recovery based on the loss of ‘consumer surplus’. Consumer surplus is
>   the difference in value between what a thing is worth commercially and the higher value
>   at which a consumer subjectively values it. So, whilst an extra few inches on the swimming pool added no financial value, the £2,500 represented Mr Forsyth’s consumer surplus:
>   to him, and him alone, the pool was a more valuable asset if it was deeper (i.e. if his
>   contract was fully performed). He had contracted for this extra depth and it had not been
>   provided, so you could argue that the award of £2,500 was compensation for loss of this
>   consumer surplus.

I'm not a microeconomist, but these terms appear to be defined wholly differently? Or am I overlooking something similar that underlies  them?

Comment: You've added another passage by Taylor & Taylor (2019): *Consumer surplus is the difference in value between what a thing is worth commercially and the higher value at which a consumer subjectively values it.* To me, this is again identical to the economist's definition of *consumer surplus*. If you believe that this is "wholly different" from the economist's definition, you should probably add more context to explain why.

Comment: @KennyLJ Yes. I'm just double-checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O'Sullivan & Hilliard write: Consumer surplus is a "type of non-financial loss" and

> can be defined as the amount by which the particular plaintiff values performance of a particular obligation over and above its market value.

This is identical to the economist's definition of *consumer surplus*.

Using Pindyck and Rubinfeld's example: If a student was willing to pay as much as $\$13$ for a rock concert ticket (this is the value she places on the "performance of a particular obligation") but only had to pay $\$12$ (this is the price or the market value of the ticket), then her consumer surplus is $$\$13-\$12=\$1.$$